# Draw Line on Graph

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, jlabel, line-drawing

I want to create a grid of 6*6 then next step is to put image Tiles column by column in each grid.A complete image is composition of all tiles in each grid. Then i want  to draw  lines over complete image formed by 6*6 grid.
I have tried with JLabel and created 6*6 grid of JLabels and image is formed completely but i was trying to draw line over image formed , i am unable to do that. Line is starting from end of the image on right side. I am strucked at this point.Please tell me to do it in someway.

Comment: Please have a look at how to post a [MCVE].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so... you want a 6*6 image tile grid? You can do that with the JPanel paint method. If you are not using JPanel, then:
this is your main class

```
  public class Main{

       public static void main(String[] args){
           MyWindow window = new MyWindow();
       }
   }
```

this is your MyWindow class:

```
public class MyWindow extends JFrame{

   public MyWindow(){
      super.setVisible(true);
      super.setSize(500,500);
      MyPanel panel = new MyPanel();
      super.setContentPane(panel);

   }
}
```

this is your MyPanel class:

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel{
   public MyPanel(){
      super.setSize(500,500);
      super.setVisible(true);

   }
   @Override
   public void paint(Graphics g){
       for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
           for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++){
               g.drawImage(theImage,i*10,j*10,null);// the tens are your image's dimensions. If your image is 100x50 then it must be i*100 and j*50
           }
       }
   }
}
```

If you ARE using JPanel, then just copy the paint method.
This will draw your image 36(6*6) times, in the form of a grid.
I hope this has helped.

NOTE: I haven't tested this, I just wrote it directly on the post. If you have an error of some kind, just reply to me.